# Angular 2: Multiple Form

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

I have a component which contains child components. Each child contains a form, built using FormBuilder. 
I have included JADE template inside the components just for clarity.
Further I load the child components using the component router.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `
        .detail-page
            .detail-header
                .ui.secondary.menu.inverted.orange
                    .item Inquiry Details
                    .right.menu
                        a.item((click)='add($event)')
                            i.plus.icon
                        a.item((click)='save($event)')
                            i.save.icon
            .detail-content 
                router-outlet
            .detail-footer
                a.item([routerLink]="['Child1']")
                a.item([routerLink]="['Child2']")
    `
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/child1',                  name: 'Child1',                 component: Child1,          useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/child2',                  name: 'Child2',                 component: Child2 }
])  
export class Parent {

    save(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // validate all child forms
        ???????
    }

}

@Component({
    template: `
        form([ngFormModel]='childForm1')
            input(type='text', [control]="field1")
            input(type='text', [control]="field2")
    `
})  
export class Child1 {

    constructor(
        private _formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) {
        this.childForm1 = this._formBuilder.group({
            field1: this.field1,
            field2: this.field2
        });
    }

}

@Component({
    template: `
        form([ngFormModel]='childForm2')
            input(type='text', [control]="field1")
            input(type='text', [control]="field2")
    `
})  
export class Child2 {

    constructor(
        private _formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) {
        this.childForm2 = this._formBuilder.group({
            field1: this.field1,
            field2: this.field2
        });
    }

}
```

I need to validate the all the child forms when the save button is pressed.

As I understand only one child component is active/initialized at the end of the routing. Thus I cannot loop over the components to validate the forms.

1. What is the best approach to design such a component where it is not user friendly to have a long vertical form but have it broken down into manageable child form components?
2. Is there a way to re-use the components created?

I was thinking I can use the dynamic component loader but still I only get access to the current loaded component.

Your suggestions/help is much appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: What about just adding all components at once and only showing a part while hiding the rest?

Comment: With hiding I mean `[hidden]="true` instead of `*ngIf="false"`(which effectively removes the content from the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! I updated my question to include the routerLink's I use to load the components on click. Do you mean to have all child templates loaded on the parent template itself and somehow hide a particular section? I could try that. The child forms as a bit lengthy but I will give that a try also.

Comment: You can still wrap the parts in components to keep the size of the template of the parent small but validation only runs for on elements that actually exist in the DOM. (If you wrap parts of the form into components, then the forms in these components would be validated individually and you have to collect the results to get the status for the whole.)

Comment: Yes I think this is a good suggestion. ie. To move the template parts to their own components but have a single form. I will give this approach a try. Thanks a lot @GünterZöchbauer.

Comment: I was able to get the validation done using the approach you suggested. Thanks again @GünterZöchbauer. If you can post an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all forms at once and just show a selection of them at once using

```
[hidden]="someExpression"
```

You can still wrap the parts in components to keep the size of the template of the parent small, but validation only runs for on elements that actually exist in the DOM. (If you wrap parts of the form into components, then the forms in these components would be validated individually and you have to collect the results to get the status for the whole.)